# Enable template path hints in production mode Magento 2

Tags: magento2, debug, template-hints

This seems like it should be straightforward, it seems as though it is not.

Is there any way to **enable template path hints in production mode** in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it myself but i will be interested in your finding :)

https://github.com/ho-nl/magento2-Ho_Templatehints/commit/ae687688221a87f73939cb9ab4f23d625ec64684